# MATLAB GUI - bring up a string

Tags: matlab, user-interface

i' m try to create a simplex and fast gui on matlab. I made a button with a callback function, but I don' t know how to bring up a string that depends upon the result of the function. For example if the result of the function is 1, must appear the string "All ok!", if the result of the function is 0, must appear the string "It' s wrong!!!".

Comment: How about an if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Static Text object or an inactive Edit Text object and modify the String property from your script with:

```
set(handles.edit_text, 'String', 'your_string')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the static/edit uicontrol is to use a `msgbox` or an `errordlg` to display the result to the user depending on the result of your function.

```
if myFunction
  msgbox ( 'All Ok' );
else
  errordlg ( 'Error in Function', 'Error' )
end
```